# C++ Using pointers to template objects

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, template-specialization

I have a class named ABC which has a class template:

```
template <class T> class ABC{}
```

In another class I am trying to store of objects ABC in a list:

```
class CDE{
private:
  list<ABC *> some_list; 
}
```

I intend to store objects of ABC which might have different class template parameters. Is it necessary to specify template even for a pointer at compile time? What if the container is supposed to store objects of different type? Is that not possible?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is it necessary to specify template even for a pointer at compile time ?

Yes.

> What if the container is supposed to store objects of different type ? Is that not possible ?

It is not (directly) possible.

There is no such thing as the class ABC.  There are only instantiations of ABC, such as `ABC<Foo>` and `ABC<Bar>`.  These are completely different classes.

You can do something like:

```
template<typename T>
class ABC : public ABC_Base
{
  ...
}

list<ABC_Base*> some_list;
```

By doing this, all of your ABC instantiations have a common base type, and you can use a base pointer arbitrarily.

Comment: This sounds reasonable enough, with a little downside. The whole reason for using templates was the make sure that objects were tightly coupled. This way there is still a chance of creating objects of ABC_Base (or its derived classes) without template type and use them in the list.

Comment: @cyrux If you make `ABC_Base` abstract, then nobody can create objects of `ABC_Base`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to either specify the template parameters in your `CDE` class, or make `CDE` a template as well.

First option:

```
class CDE {
private:
    list< ABC<int>* > some_list;
};
```

Second option:

```
template <class T>
class CDE {
private:
    list< ABC<T>* > some_list;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The list can only store a single type.  Different instantiations of a template are different types.  If this is satisfactory, you can do it like this:

`template <class T> class CDE{ private: list<ABC<T> *> some_list; }`

If you need to use different types, perhaps you could create a non-template base class for ABC and store pointers to that. (ie. use an interface)